# landing page - sharing with another Business unit

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page, cloudpage, sfmc-business-unit

I'm doing research about landing pages within Salesforce Marketing Cloud. Am i able to share landing pages in beween Business units?

thank you!

Answer (score 3):

No - Cloud Pages are linked to single a Business Unit. However, when building them, you can use Content builder and have all your elements reside in Shared content across multiple Business Units - making creating similar pages in more BUs quicker tha recreating all from scratch.

If you can be more specific on your use case, more exact advice can be provided.

Comment: Thank you, I was aware of the Content Builder shared folder option. Good to be sure now it's impossible to share the whole landing page.

Comment: Unfortunately it’s not possible indeed. Remember to mark the answer as accepted

Comment: If you need to provide some sort of template you can save the base code of the landing page as a code snippet, which again can be shared through the shared folders. It's still not optimal but allows for some sort of centralised landing page templating across business units

Comment: Thank you, the question got answered. I'm not sure why it's on hold.

Comment: I also do think it was clear - can you still mark the answer as accepted, even though it has been put on hold?